# scrollTo functionality for dynamic content

Tags: jquery, drupal-8

I'm trying to create a 'scrollTo' link for content higher on the page to a spot with more information lower on the page.  I currently have it working for one item with the code below.  Both sets of code can be modified as needed.

**Markup (Twig):**

```
<a id="scroll-src-{{ term.id }}" class="content-scroll">
<!-- other page content -->
<div id="scroll-dest-{{ term.id }}" class="content-scroll"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
if($('.content-scroll').length) {
  $('#scroll-src-16').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scroll-dest-16').offset().top - 87
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

As you can see, I only have this working for one item: term `16`.  How can I abstract/modify this to work with all *term ids* that get populated?

This is built in Drupal 8 and utilizes the Views module. and I am unsure if I need to use drupal.settings / drupal.behaviors for the optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

**Jquery**

```
if($('.content-scroll').length) {
  $('.scroll-link').click(function() {
  var number = $(this).attr('data-scroll-id');
    $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#scroll-dest-'+number).offset().top - 87
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="scroll-src-{{ term.id }}" data-scroll-id="{{ term.id }}" class="scroll-link content-scroll">
<!-- other page content -->
<div id="scroll-dest-{{ term.id }}" class="content-scroll"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="scroll-src-{{ term.id }}" class="content-scroll button" data-id="{{ term.id }}">
<!-- other page content -->
<div id="scroll-dest-{{ term.id }}" class="content-scroll"></div>



if($('.content-scroll').length) {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('#scroll-dest-'+$(this).data('id')).offset().top - 87
         }, 750);
    });
}
```

I suggest giving every button a data attribute and a class to bind the click on. In the click event use the data attribute to scroll to the right ID.